# how to create a Docker local private repository

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, docker-registry, docker-repository

I created a local docker repository in my server.
 When I try to push the image into it, there is an error.
 I need an HTTPS connection.
 How do I get an HTTPS for my own docker registry?

**os:** ubuntu 16.x
**Docker version:** 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a 
**Already Tried:**
Adding the below lines into /etc/docker/daemon.json,

`{
  "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
 }`

**Expected:** I should be able to push and pull images into my own server containing docker registry

Comment: I use a local registry (dev machine) and an SSH tunnel to push images to a remote server. The server thinks it's talking to a local registry and port 5000 isn't exposed (at either end).

Comment: sorry I don't understand @Chris

Comment: I've expanded on that as an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid exposing your registry to the wider internet while still being able to pull images from it you can:

1. Run a local registry on your dev machine, to which you push images
2. ssh to your server with a reverse tunnel:

   `ssh -R 5000:localhost:5000 myhost`

   (listen on port 5000 of the remote machine (`-R 5000`) and tunnel back to `localhost:5000` on the local machine)
3. Now, on `myhost` you can `docker pull localhost:5000/someImage`, but it's actually seamlessly connecting through an encrypted tunnel back to the registry on your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a local unsecured registry. 
For that, you need to add an exception in your /etc/docker/daemon.json, [this way](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
 }
```

The same link shows how to use a self-signed certificate.

Eventually, using an actual certificate is juste a step further, but you may not need one for development purpose.

**EDIT** :
You need to restart your daemon after that :

```
service docker restart
```

Comment: i should replace ["**myregistrydomain.com**:5000"] to this right?  ["**myip**:5000"] @marvin

Comment: your ip or whatever name you gave it within your /etc/hosts

Comment: i have done that but its still `http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client` @marvin

Comment: I should have mention that you need to restart the daemon. I add it to my answer

Comment: still, not fixed :'( @marvin

Comment: You still have the message stating you need https? It should not. I have a local repo and using it with the unsecured config, and its working well. Can you connect directly to the repo through 5000?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188344/discussion-between-aathith-rajendran-and-marvin).